# how can I set useState variable under useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have 1 functions `checkCondition`  that should return true/false based on some logic check. and I will like to pass the return value into the variable `isMatched` under component. I have tried to use useEffect and then debug. but the variable does not changed at all

```
export function checkCondition(): boolean {
  ...
}

export default function App() {
const [isMatched, setMatched] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{
  const aa = checkCondition()
  console.log({aa})
  setMatched(aa) //get correct expected
  console.log({isMatched}) //always false
}, [isMatched])
  console.log({isMatched}) //always false

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are stuck in an infinite loop by the way you are calling setMatched inside of a useEffect which runs when isMatched gets changed

Comment: try `console.log(checkCondition())` also the first `console.log` in your code  inside useEffect will log previous value of `isMatched` as state update is async

Comment: Hm ..so how should I fix the infinite loop?

Comment: before updating the state value check if previous state is same as next state if it is same don't update state. inside useEffect

Comment: There are multiple ways to fix the infinite loop. But it depends on when you want this effect to run. If it happens just once on mount then use @bertidda answer bellow. If you want it to run multiple times, then I recommend having something other than isMatched as the dependency. Hard to tell what scenario is best based on your example so far.

Comment: Just curious after thinking about it why it will be infinite loop? If isMatched from checkConditiom return continuely true or false like true then true I thought useEffect should not run in that case

Answer (score 2):

I am walking through the code you have put here:

```
const [isMatched, setMatched] = useState(false)
```

You have set initial value of `isMatched` as `false`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  ...
}, [isMatched])
```

Here the `useEffect` is registered as callback but not run yet.

```
console.log({isMatched})
```

Console logs `false` because `useEffect` has not run yet.
Then the `return()` JSX is rendered.
Now `useEffect` is called.

```
const aa = checkCondition() //aa gets checkCondition value
console.log({aa}) //aa is logged to console
setMatched(aa)//isMatched is set to aa's value, but this update will not happen immediately
console.log({isMatched})//This will output false(since initial value of isMatched is false), setState doesn't update immediately remember?
```

Each line explained above.

Now this `useEffect` has been given deps `[isMatched]`, which means this code will run once in the beginning, then every time `isMatched` value changes. Now why would you want to do this, I don't know, I assume you saw the lint warning saying `React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'isMatched'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)eslint` and put it there, which is wrong because you are only using it for a `console.log`. Either way, now whenever you call setMatched with a different value than it was **previously**(in this cycle previous value is `false`), it will rerun the `useEffect` callback.

This means if `checkCondition` output is `true`, `useEffect` will run once more, if it is `false` it will not. It will not fall into an infinite loop here as boolean values are primitive, so `false===false` and `true===true` comparisons are both `true`. If `checkCondition` output were a object reference it has the potential to fall into an infinite loop, because the `isMatched` dependency most likely would point to a different reference every time.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid infinite loop as commented, update your state this way,

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  const aa = checkCondition()
  setMatched(() => aa));
}, [])
```

Comment: That will only work if he wants the check to be done on mount

Answer (score 0):

```
function App(props){
// init update
const [isMatched, setMatched] = useState(props.matched);

//updates through props
useEffect(() => { 
setMatched(props.matched);
},[props.matched]);

// update through object
return <div onClick={() => setMatched(true)}>this</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isMatched, setMatched] = useState(() => checkCondition());

useEffect(()=> {
  const matched = checkCondition();
  setMatched(matched);
}, [isMatched]);
```